# I'm having a lot of css flexbox issues

Tags: css, flexbox

I've recently started learning CSS Flexbox. Even though I'm being able to follow the curriculum, I'm having issues with some codes.
In the code below, I'm trying to use these two properties I learnt recently, **flex-shrink** and **flex-grow**, inside of a flex-container, the first two of the four div boxes are visible but the other two are not visible in the screen layout. Can someone please explain me that why I'm having such issues and what should I do?
Thank you.
Here's my code-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #box-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 300px;
    }
    
    #box-1 {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
      height: 50px;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    #box-2 {
      background-color: orangered;
      height: 50px;
      flex-grow: 2;
    }
    
    #box-3 {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
      height: 50px;
      flex-shrink: 2;
    }
    
    #box-4 {
      background-color: orangered;
      height: 50px;
      flex-shrink: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="box-container">
    <div id="box-1"></div>
    <div id="box-2"></div>
    <div id="box-3"></div>
    <div id="box-4"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: box-3 and box-4 are set with width:0 because they hasn't any width property. for example flex-grow:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the boxes has any content. The first two boxes can expand because of `flex-grow` and the next two shrink by default even if you don't specify `flex-shrink`. This is why only the first two boxes are visible.

If you want to let them take equal widths with no content you can use `flex: 1 1 auto;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #box-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 300px;
    }
    
    #box-container > * {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    #box-1 {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
    }
    
    #box-2 {
      background-color: orangered;
    }
    
    #box-3 {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
    }
    
    #box-4 {
      background-color: orangered;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="box-container">
    <div id="box-1"></div>
    <div id="box-2"></div>
    <div id="box-3"></div>
    <div id="box-4"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It did work. Thank you. But can you tell me why you used the symbols with #box-container the second time?

Comment: @samira That's a [combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators). I used that to avoid repeating styles.